# Getting JSON response WITH cURL

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I've already lost a couple days struggling with this.

Here is my cURL request from the command line:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: text/html" http://laravel.project/api/v1/users/4
```

This returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sun, 29 Mar 2015 10:33:36 GMT
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImNPTkZIYVJZSVRKaHBOZTR3SWh0dHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiblpZYVJlN2dBY1ljejNIYUQycXpsNXRWd1I5a3JSRG8wSWdDOWlHVTMrYUcrdDBNVmVuZUNkOGtJb2M4bXFpTFF3cUdoTFZOVXBWXC82Q1luSGd5bjJBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0ZTEwOWQxMmVhMzY2NjI1Yzc1MTBmZmRmYjUyOGQwNDlhYzRjOTNiM2FiOWIyN2E1YjA0OTM4YTUxZmNmMzMzIn0%3D; expires=Sun, 29-Mar-2015 12:33:36 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly

{
"data":{
  "id":4,
  "name":"Helena",
  "email":"hh@gmail.com",
  "created_at":"2015-03-26 21:13:16",
  "updated_at":"2015-03-26 21:13:16"
  }
}
```

So everything looks fine: the Content-type is correctly set and response is in JSON.

But now watch what happens if I consume the API with curl in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $final_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

return json_decode($result);
```

I get this response:

```
{#165
  +"data": {#167
    +"id": 4
    +"name": "Helena"
    +"email": "hh@gmail.com"
    +"created_at": "2015-03-26 21:13:16"
    +"updated_at": "2015-03-26 21:13:16"
  }
}
```

And, if I return the `$result` without `json_decode`, I get this:

```
"{
  "data":{
    "id":4,
    "name":"Helena",
    "email":"hh@gmail.com",
    "created_at":"2015-03-26 21:13:16",
    "updated_at":"2015-03-26 21:13:16"
  }
}"
```

The correct response but inside quotes. I've read in PHP docs that `curl_opt_returntranfer` returns the result as a string but I can't be the only person on the planet that just wants to get the JSON.

This is my `ApiController` class:

```html
class ApiController extends Controller {

    // Base controller for API Controllers

    protected $statusCode = 200;

    protected function respond($data)
    {
        return Response::json([
           'data' => $data,

        ]);
    }

    protected function respondNotFound($message = 'No data found')
    {
        return Response::json([
            'error' => [
                'message' => $message,
                'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode(),
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my `UserController`:

```html
class UserController extends ApiController {

  public function show($user)
    {

       if ($user == null)
            return $this->setStatusCode(404)->respondNotFound('User not found');

        return $this->respond($user);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your function that handle the request (might be show action in UsersController). Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for attention, updated with more info in Edit 1

Comment: I copy your code and put it into my Laravel, I got no double quotes. Are using cUrl inside Laravel project and view the result on a web browser?

Comment: I'm using POSTMAN to send a request to my client controller that uses CURL to reach the API application.

Comment: You are using different accept headers between your cURL command line call and your PHP example.  While I would think the PHP example would be correct, in that you are looking for JSON, is the API not responding appropriately to `application/json` vs. `text/html`?

Answer (score 0):

> And if I return the $result without json_decode i get this: The correct response but inside quotes

nope, what makes you think that? i guess the problem is how you are printing it, you are most likely printing it with `var_export($result)` or `var_dump($result)` or `echo json_encode($result);` which is adding the quotes. if you just want the json, just echo it with `echo $result;`, no extra processing, just echo the string as-is, it's already json.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: text/html" http://laravel.project/api/v1/users/4 | tr -d '"'
```

Comment: Actually when I run the cURL command in the command line everything works fine.

The problem comes when I try to do the same in PHP

Comment: Try to remove: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));. 

json_decode converts **string**

Comment: Im still getting my json response between " "....

I can't believe I'm stuck with such a problem for 48 hours now:

"{"data":{"id":4,"name":"Helena","email":"hh@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-26 21:13:16","updated_at":"2015-03-26 21:13:16"}}"

Comment: @Borjante use trim function and remove double quotes

Comment: I can't... not even with sub_str()

Comment: Thanks @TomerM anyway. I finally forgot about using plain cURL and i'm using Guzzle now.

Answer (score -1):

```
$response = (string)$result;
                    $resp_arr = explode("<!DOCTYPE",$response);
                    $obj = json_decode(trim($japi_arr[0]));
                    if(isset($obj[0]))
                    {
                    $rsp_id = $obj[0]->id;
                    $rsp_name = $obj[0]->name;
```